# How do I get the current user username in Spotify Apps?

Tags: spotify

I have tried using sp.core.user.canonicalUsername and m.User in various variants, I even tried to get the username by traversing through the m.playlists.starredPlaylist. This is probably easy but I can't find it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from a Spotify employee:

"Personally-indentifiable information like username won't be available, ever."

Typically, they want you to use Facebook Auth for any social features.

Apparently Spotify will be releasing new documentation in a week or so, so keep an eye out and see if it sheds any light.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be available, but you can obtain an unique user id with `sp.core.getAnonymousUserId()`

Comment: Your app will not be approved if you use sp.core

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can use

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
models.session.anonymousUserID
```

From the [Api Reference](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/a5a59ca068.html):

```
anonymousUserID  string     Get an anonymous user ID, which is unique per-user, per-application.
```