# Is there a way to search currently playing songs for every user using the Spotify API?

Tags: spotify

I just want to experiment writing a little app that will let you know how many people on spotify are listening to the same song you are. Not just your friends but everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given the responses to similar questions that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658657/spotify-apps-api-get-other-users-playlists), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551114/access-users-data-in-spotify-app), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658657/spotify-apps-api-get-other-users-playlists) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696537/how-do-i-get-the-current-user-username-in-spotify-apps) I would say that it is probably not possible for privacy reasons, as the spotify API does not intend to let you access the users spotify id which would be required to get the tracks you where listening to.

Comment: Yup, not possible. Considered using Last.fm? Could still check currently playing track in Spotify.